# How to get a graphical class diagram of solution?

Tags: .net

I have .net solution with many projects and classes. To understand it I want to get a graphical scheme of classes. How to get it? Are there any programs or tools to do this?

Answer (score 0):

With VisualStudio you can do that for a project by rightClicking/Show Class Diagram but I don't think it is possible with an entire solution..